# Error on Post Method query_builder::QueryFragment / query_builder::QueryFragment

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket, rocket

I am relatively new to rust and have really enjoyed playing around with it. However I am stuck on an error for my CRUD application using Diesel and Rocket. I have a main.rs, model.rs and schema.rs.

I get an error with my POST method that uses the User struct i created.

I am using a postgres DB i have running in the background on docker, Diesel and rocket for routing.

My models.rs

```
use super::schema::users;
use diesel::{prelude::*, table, Queryable, Insertable, RunQueryDsl};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Queryable, Debug, Insertable)]
#[table_name= "users"]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub user_name: String,
    pub email_address: String,
}
```

My main.rs (included everything for detail but really question is about the Post method - create_user

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

mod models;
mod schema;

use rocket_sync_db_pools::{database};
use models::{User};
use rocket::{serde::json::Json};
use diesel::{RunQueryDsl};
use schema::users;

#[database("my_db")]
pub struct Db(rocket_sync_db_pools::diesel::PgConnection);

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello World"
}

#[get("/<id>")]
fn get_user(id: i32) -> Json<User> {
    Json(User {
        id: id,
        first_name: "A Fist Name".to_string(),
        last_name: "A Last Name".to_string(),
        user_name: "A User Name".to_string(),
        email_address: "AnEmail@email.com".to_string(),
    })
}

#[post("/", data = "<user>")]
async fn create_user(connection: Db, user: Json<User>) -> Json<User> {
    connection.run(move |c| {
    diesel::insert_into(users::table)
    .values(&user.into_inner())
    .get_result(c)
    })
    .await
    .map(Json)
    .expect("There was an error saving the user")
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let rocket = rocket::build();

    rocket
    .attach(Db::fairing())
    .mount("/", routes![index])
    .mount("/users", routes![get_user, create_user])

}
```

Dependencies from Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
diesel = "2.0.2"
diesel_cli = { version = "1.4.1", default-features = false, features = ["postgres"] }
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }
rocket_sync_db_pools = { version = "0.1.0-rc.2", features = ["diesel_postgres_pool"] }
serde = "1.0.140"
```

The error message

```
    --> src/main.rs:66:6
     |
66   |     .get_result(c)
     |      ^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`with_auth_rust_rocket_diesel_binary`)
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` for `DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, &i32>>>`
     = note: 123 redundant requirements hidden
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` for `DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, &i32>>>`
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::insertable::InsertValues<table, _>` for `DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, &i32>>>`
     = note: 3 redundant requirements hidden
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::QueryFragment<_>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, &i32>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::first_name, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::last_name, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::user_name, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::email_address, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>), table>, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::private::Insert, diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<(columns::id, columns::first_name, columns::last_name, columns::user_name, columns::email_address)>>`
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::LoadQuery<'_, _, _>` for `diesel::query_builder::InsertStatement<table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::id, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Integer, &i32>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::first_name, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::last_name, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::user_name, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<diesel::insertable::ColumnInsertValue<columns::email_address, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>), table>>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::get_result`
    --> /Users/me/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.2/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1679:15
     |
1679 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::get_result`
```

I have reviewed both Diesel, Rocket and Rust documentation and worked worked through other examples for what I can find online however still do not quite get what i am doing incorrectly. Thanks in advance for any help.

I tried to create a post method that uses Diesel to take a Json version of my User object and insert it into my database.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this question without knowing the exact versions of the involved crates. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: Added dependencies from Cargo.toml - thank you @weiznich

Comment: Hello! Can you give a link to the repository? It would be great to reproduce the error locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mismatch between the diesel version used by your project (2.0.2) and the diesel version provided by rocket_sync_db_pools (1.4.8). This means the `c` in `connection.run(move |c| {` is just a completely different type than expected by `get_result`, even if the types share the same name.